# Run JS only on pages with my widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get a widget to only load javascript on a page where the widget is present.

I've tried adding the add action in the 'showWidget' didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

### PHP

```
wp_register_sidebar_widget('MyWidget','MyWidget', 'showWidget');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addScript'); //now the script appears on every page

function addScript()
{
    wp_register_script('MyWidgetJs', plugins_url( '/script.js' , __FILE__), array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('MyWidgetJs');
}
function showWidget($args)
{
    // add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addScript'); //I tried this but it doesn't work :(
    wp_enqueue_script('MyWidgetJs');
    extract($args);
    /* do widget stuff */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the new version of WordPress supports this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.3

Register your script, but don't enqueue it. In your widget PHP, add in the wp_enqueue_script('your_script_name'); and it'll load it only when your widget is used and place it in the footer.

You are going to upgrade to 3.3, right? :)

SO, something like this should work just fine:

```
wp_register_sidebar_widget('MyWidget','MyWidget', 'showWidget');
function showWidget($args) {
    wp_enqueue_script('MyWidgetJs');
    extract($args);
    /* do widget stuff */
}
```

Comment: Re: *In your widget PHP, add in...*, can you offer example code to illustrate, to make it more clear?

Comment: Done! I took the code from the previous sample and packaged it all up. You still need to register your scripts as you normally would (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [is_active_widget()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_active_widget) conditional to do something like:

```
<?php
if ( is_active_widget('MyWidget') ) {
     add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addScript'); 
}
?>
```

using your above code the final widget may look like:

```
<?php
 if ( is_active_widget('MyWidget') ) {
         add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addScript'); 
    }

function addScript()
{
    wp_register_script('MyWidgetJs', plugins_url( '/script.js' , __FILE__), array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('MyWidgetJs');
}
function showWidget($args)
{
    wp_enqueue_script('MyWidgetJs');
    extract($args);
    /* do widget stuff */
}
```

Comment: sorry but your example doesn't work no matter what I try to put into is_active_widget. the codex on it is also very vague. It seems to check if the widget is active in general, not on the page only.

Comment: @janw  See if this question helps: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2302/loading-scripts-only-if-a-particular-shortcode-or-widget-is-present